# How do you render hashes as JSON in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-3

I found how to render ActiveRecord objects in Rails 3, however I cannot figure out how to render any custom objects.  I am writing an app without ActiveRecord.  I tried doing something like this:

```
class AppController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  ...
  def start
    app.start
    format.json { render :json => {'ok'=>true} }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very close.  However, it does not automatically convert the hash to json.  This was the final result:

```
class AppControlls < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def start
    app.start
    respond_with( { :ok => true }.to_json )
  end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: { :ok => true }.json gives NoMethodError: undefined method `json' for {:ok=>true}:Hash

Comment: to_json gives no error, but I believe it is not required. (Auto conversion works fine for me). Note. for auto conversion to work :format must be json.

Answer (score 7):

When you specify a `respond_to`, then in your actions you would make a matching `respond_with`:

```
class AppControlls < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    hash = { :ok => true }
    respond_with(hash)
  end
end
```

It looks like you're conflating the old `respond_to do |format|` style blocks with the new `respond_to`, `respond_with` syntax. [This edgerails.info post](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2009/08/06/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with/) explains it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
class AppController < ApplicationController

respond_to :json

def index
  hash = { :ok => true }
  respond_with(hash.as_json)
end

end
```

You should never use to_json to create a representation, only to consume the representation.

Answer (score 0):

`format.json { render json: { ok: true } }` should work

Answer (score 0):

For those getting a NoMethodError, try this:

```
class AppController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  ...
  def start
    app.start
    render json: { :ok => true }
  end
end
```